# NE5532 slew rate

Tags: operational-amplifier, slew-rate

[image]

datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532.pdf

I saw in most opAmps this rate was given as V/us, for example, for LM741 it was 0.5V/us. **Is this 9V/ms a typing error?** Because if it is not, then this NE5532 is way slower than the LM741 which is a very ancient opAmp(I have been told so many times).

Comment: Valid question, not sure why someone downvoted it. Typos in datasheets are very annoying sometimes.

Comment: half a century ago microfarads were printed on parts as MFD  as well

Comment: @Hearth I will try to send a feedback email about this to TI. edit: I cannot find a way to do that, it should not be that hard.

Comment: Argument: typos that can be resolved by looking for the authorative parts in a datasheet (in this case, the obvious table, the short description *and* the part website) don't make great questions, though, @Hearth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a typo.  If you look in the specs section you'll see it specified as V/μs.

[image]

Also in the features section:
High Slew Rate: 9 V/μs Typ

Comment: ok, I just wanted to be sure, thanks.